# Drawing Lines in html

Tags: html

How can i draw something like this in Html ?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
   <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
   <line x1="200" y1="50" x2="200" y2="150" style="stroke:rgb(255,250,0);stroke-width:2" />
   <line x1="200" y1="50" x2="300" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
   <line x1="200" y1="150" x2="300" y2="150" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but how i can show lines and text side by side

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following: 
https://jsfiddle.net/qj0672yx/2/

```
#leftbox { 
    float:left;
    margin-top:65px;
    margin-right: 10px;
            } 
#rightbox{ 
    float:right; 
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
            }     
#middlebox{ 
    float:left;   
    margin-right:0px;
            } 

<div id = "leftbox"> 
<h2>TESTTESTTEST </h2> </div>

<div>

</div id = "middlebox">
    <svg height="210">
       <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
       <line x1="200" y1="50" x2="200" y2="150" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
       <line x1="200" y1="50" x2="300" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
       <line x1="200" y1="150" x2="300" y2="150" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    </svg>
    </div>

    <div id = "rightbox"> 
    <h2>TESTTESTTEST </h2> </div>
    </div>
```

However using bootstrap for its grid system and ease to specify and locate the divs would be more logical in your situation. See the link for grid system:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/